# Probabilistic interpretation for Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

It is well known that if $X_t$ is a stochastic process that solves the SDE
$$dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)\,\mathrm{d}t + \sigma(X_t,t)\,\mathrm{d}W_t,$$
with $W_t$ a Wiener process, then the associated probability density $p(x,t)$ solves
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot (\mu p) + \frac 12 \nabla \nabla : (Dp),$$
where $D_{ij} =\sum_{k} \sigma_{ik}\sigma_{jk}$ is symmetric, positive semi-definite. [(as summarized e.g. here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)

Now, in [the same article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation), it is written that by interpreting the stochastic SDE in the **Stratonovich** sense rather than the **Ito** sense, one instead arrives at the corresponding equation
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot (\mu p) + \frac 12 \sum_{i,k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( \sigma_{ik} \sum_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left[\sigma_{kj} p\right]\right).$$
I'm wondering if there is yet a third way to interpret the SDE which would lead to a parabolic equation in divergence-form for the probability density? I.e. to 
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot (\mu p) + \frac 12 \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( D_{ij} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j}\right).$$
The motivation for the last form is that it seems to arise very natural in physics. Does anyone know if that's possible? Thank you.

Comment: I'm interested to know what you mean by it arises naturally in physics. Is there a mathematical advantage to that; is it experimentally easier to measure or something understood; or does it happen to show up in a couple of famous equations? Can you give a some examples?

Answer (score 3):

The divergence-form of the Fokker-Planck equation arises if $\sigma$ is scalar and separable in space and time, 
$$\sigma_{ij}(x,t)=f(x)g(t)\delta_{ij}.$$ 
Define $\bar{p}=fp$, $d\bar{t}/dt=g^2$, $d\bar{x}_i/dx_i=1/f$, $\bar{\mu}_i=\mu_i/(fg^2)$, then the Stratonovich FP equation
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=-\sum_{i}\frac{d}{dx_i}(\mu_i p)+\tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{ijk}\frac{d}{dx_{i}}\left(\sigma_{ik}\frac{d}{dx_j}(\sigma_{kj} p)\right)$$
transforms (upon multiplication of both sides by $f/g^2$) into
$$\frac{d\bar{p}}{d\bar{t}}=-\sum_{i}\frac{d}{d\bar{x}_i}(\bar{\mu}_i\bar{p})+\tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i}\frac{d^2}{d\bar{x}_i^2}\bar{p},$$
which has the desired divergence-form.

Comment: Only in dimension d=1....

Comment: indeed, or at least $\sigma$ should be a scalar --- thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a thing called $A$-type stochastic differential equation that does that. See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11467-017-0718-2.pdf